# CollectionView scrollbars visibility

Tags: maui, maui-windows

CollectionView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" does not imply a scrollbar which is always visible (as the enum name seems to state), rather (this is on a windows 10 machine), the scrollbar is visible only by hoovering mouse where it eventually will be visible.
Why is this not working somewhat like e.g. Microsoft Teams (Version 1.5.00.9163 in my case)?
(Where it is visible if the mouse is hoovered over anywhere in the control/view (and even growing in size when mouse hoovers over the then visible scrollbar)